# git log --pretty=oneline --format="%Cgreen%h %Creset%s" --grep="Linux 3.0." -n 20 is not giving any output

Tags: android, git

```sh
mkdir android-kernel 
cd android-kernel

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common
cd common
git log --pretty=oneline --format="%Cgreen%h %Creset%s" \
        --grep="Linux 2.6." -n 20
```

now it is not giving any output and `git log` is also empty.

kindly tell me now what I have to do.

Comment: What does a plain "git log" give you?
Do you have something in your .git folder?

Comment: What do you mean by 700 MB repo? Is your repository cloned correctly? git log should give *some* output. It can't be empty.

Comment: The only commit has the message "empty commit"

Comment: Gosh, are many people getting the same error? Probably something _broken_ in the server side?

Comment: It might be than the grep is applied after the "oneline" filter. So if the text "Linux 2.6." doesn't appear on the first line of the commit it might not result in a match for the grep.